# Plunkr: Test Angular 2 Final Plunk Not working

Tags: angular, plunker

Could any one please tell me why the Angular 2 Final Test Plunk that I am using (https://plnkr.co/edit/JY0hcFdaziIsFFJmRaz3?p=preview) is not working?

I get this error on the console:

```
Refused to display 'https://run.plnkr.co/QdUdeWWKa25MFN9V/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
https://run.plnkr.co/QdUdeWWKa25MFN9V/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 522 ()
```

Comment: The other reason was that the run server for Plunker was under unprecedented load recently and was suffering from intermittent outages. It has since been scaled out and performing better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there were few problems,

1) **app.component** should be inside **app folder**
2) **app.module** file should be inside **app folder**
3) in **systemjs.config.js** file, **rxjs library** reference was required.
4) removed `routing` from **imports:[BrowserModule,...]**

Working Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/ONGeKcu0sVfQqR7gpHZY?p=preview

```
'rxjs':  'npm:rxjs',
```